# Modernizr guide

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I was curious if anyone knew of a good Modernizr guide, I am having a difficult time grasping how it works. I know it is not just load the script and tada. So if anyone could direct me to a good guide it would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you seen: http://www.modernizr.com/docs/ ?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to find maybe something quick to get some understanding before I dive into the documentation.

Comment: isnt that what the documentation is for?

Comment: the documentation sucks my balls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a 'A List Apart' article which is a bit more of a tutorial style introduction than the standard documentation.  You may find it easier going:  [Taking Advantage of HTML5 and CSS3 with Modernizr](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/)

Answer (score 2):

I found [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) very useful when I started looking into Modernizr: [Detecting HTML5 Features](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/detect.html)